# how to set html anchor tag href from server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using html anchor tag in following way.

```
<a id='ahome' runat='server'>Home</a>
```

Now in backend C# I am setting update href like

```
ahome.href="#divhome"
```

but in front end on html ,it is rendring like

```
<a id='ahome' runat='server' href='.../pages/#divhome'>Home</a>
```

I want to render it as

```
<a id='ahome' runat='server' href='#divhome'>Home</a>
```

no extra .../pages requred in anchor tags.
how to set only href='#divhome' from server side means from backend c#?

Comment: What is being rendered doesn't make sense. You are setting it to #divhome but "divhome" doesn't appear in the rendered code. Are you changing it elsewhere? Why set it server side if it is a constant value?

Comment: I am setting server side constant values based on condtion,user access rights. and I am trying to render as ahome.href="#divhome" but on aspx output page it is rendering like ..../pages/#divhome(correcttion) here.can you look this.

Comment: It will take relative path based on the current URL. Also value you are assigning is kind of location on the same page. So clicking on it would take you to that location only. Does it matter for you that how it is being rendered? Does it not redirecting properly when you click on the link?

Comment: exactly , it dont' want that relative path. I have to have path only like href='#divhome' ,because it has some navigation on that link, can you tell why this is happens